# i want to compare strings in string type array with one another in java

Tags: java

I have tried following code but it didn't work out,how can i do this?

```
 for(int i=0;i<Name.length;i++){
    for(int j=i+1; j<Name.length;j++){
        if(Name[i].equals(Name[j]))
        { 
            count++;
            person[i]=Name[i];
        }
    }
 }
 System.out.println("Repeated Names:");
 for(int i=0; i<Name.length;i++){
    System.out.println(person[i]);
 }
 System.out.println("Count Of Repeated Names: "+count);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please fix the code in your answer.

Comment: How did @Radiodef know what the code was?

Comment: I was wondering that too....

Comment: @Gendarme Some of the code was hidden because of formatting. There needs to be an empty line before a code block. Go to the revision history and click 'source' on the first revision to see what I mean more clearly.

Comment: this question seem irrelevant to you people but may be beneficial for someone other who experienced problem like me

Answer (score 2):

In your if statement where you assign Name[i] to person[i], 'i' will increment with the loop instead of incrementing only when something is added to person[]. Instead, use your count variable (make sure count was set to 0 before any of the loops):

```
if(Name[i].equals(Name[j]))
{
    boolean found=false;

    for (String s: person) {
        if(Name[j].equals(s)) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(!found) {
        person[count] = Name[i];
        count++;
    }
}
```

Also, notice the added for loop in the if statement. If you don't check for and already found name, you can potentially add the same duplicate more than once and you can get an out of bounds exception. So if your name array is:

{"John","John","John"}

your loop will add the second and third John on the first iteration, and the third John again on the second iteration.

Lastly to print the person array without printing nulls or garbage, you can use your count variable again:

```
for(int i=0; i<count;i++){
    System.out.println(person[i]);
}
```